# Any tutorials for Node.js using Cloud 9?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I am looking everywhere hoping to find a tutorial that shows me how to use Cloud 9 to build Node.js apps. Anyone know of any good resources?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are asking how to set it up locally,  see here : http://www.cambus.net/setting-up-a-node-js-development-environment-with-npm-and-cloud9-ide-installed-locally/

Getting started link : http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/20640198-lesson-3-writing-a-node-js-hello-world-program

Comment: I have come across some articles about setting up locally. what I'm looking for is an actual tutorial showing me how I can get a basic nodejs app working. The commands I type on my local Ubuntu box don't seem to work in the c9 console.

Comment: See this : http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/20640198-lesson-3-writing-a-node-js-hello-world-program If there is still a problem, say what commands you are trying and what errors are showing up.

Comment: I've edited the answer so that you can mark the answer as correct.